# fix the code to prevent dropdown menu from closing when on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got the code from w3scgool and modified it. The dropdown menu opens but when I click inside of it - submenu, then it closes. Here is the pure JavaScript code.

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-btn');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === 'block') {

      dropdownContent.style.display = 'none';
    } else {

      dropdownContent.style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
}
```

```css
nav.side-nav {
  order: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: stretch;
  margin-bottom: 0.67rem;
}

nav.side-nav ul {
  margin: 0;
}

nav.side-nav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9dadc;
  border-left: 1px solid #d9dadc;
  border-right: 1px solid #d9dadc;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

nav.side-nav li:first-child {
  background: #092a31;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

nav.side-nav li:not(:first-child):hover {
  background: #cda600;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*dropdown menu*/

.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<nav class="side-nav">
  <ul>

    <li style="text-align:left;">some1</li>
    <li href="#">some1</li>
    <li href="#">some1</li>
    <li href="#">some1</li>

    <li id="navDrop" class="dropdown-btn">
      <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <form>
        <a class="dropdown-container-link" id="navItem1" href="#">Submenu1</a><br>

        <a class="dropdown-container-link" id="navItem2" href="#">Submenu2</a><br>

        <a class="dropdown-container-link" id="navItem3" href="#">Submenu3</a><br>

        <a class="dropdown-container-link" id="navItem4" href="#">Submenu4</a>
      </form>
    </div>

    <li href="#">Menu</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

</html>
```

I am new to JS. Could someone navigate/show how to edit the code to prevent dropdown from closing when click on its submenu. 
Update: took out the onclick feature. Took from my code too.
Any suggestions about the code because it stays the same. In this case I am using just JS without jquery library.

Comment: Please update your HTML to make it easier to answer.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I updated the code with html part

Comment: Your menu items have `onclick` attributes that set `window.location.href`, which cause the page to reload. Remove those attributes.

Comment: You have an onclick event triggering for all the items which is causing the page to refresh. Any specific reason you are using the onclick ? If not just remove to see the drop-down.

Comment: If you have used any CSS or library please specify it. Because we can't see the dropo down effect

Comment: Thanks both of you, I took out the onclick attributes, but it stays the same. I needed the dropdown menu stay open during I click on Submenu buttons.

Comment: You can edit the runnable code by clicking on the "edit the above snippet" link below the snippet while [edit]ing the question.  That way you don't inadvertently remove the snippet as with your last edit. Please try it out by editing the snippet to remove the onclick attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making the modifications suggested by @Heretic Monkey and @Ganesh chaitanya, you can simplify your code by using map() instead of a for loop, and again classList.toggle() instead of else if.
just modify your css a little with a new class that you add to your div. Like that

```js
    var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
    // here dropdown.map() don't work, use 
    Array.prototype.map.call(dropdown, function(drop) {
      drop.addEventListener("click", function() {
        drop.classList.toggle("active");
        var dropdownContent = drop.nextElementSibling;
        //use classList.toggle with the new class added at the div
        dropdownContent.classList.toggle("disp-container");
      });
    });
```

```css
nav.side-nav li:not(:first-child):hover {
      background: #cda600;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    /*dropdown menu*/
    
    /*remove display here*/
    .dropdown-container {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      padding-left: 8px;
    }
    /*create a new class and add display here*/
    .disp-container {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
        <nav class="side-nav">
          <ul>
            <li style="text-align:left;">some1</li>
            <li href="#">some1</li>
            <li href="#">some1</li>
            <li href="#">some1</li>
    
            <li id="navDrop" class="dropdown-btn">
              <a href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
            <!-- add your new class here -->
            <div class="disp-container dropdown-container">
              <form>
                <a class="dropdown-container-link" id="navItem1" href="#">Submenu1</a><br />
                <a class="dropdown-container-link" id="navItem2" href="#">Submenu2</a><br />
                <a class="dropdown-container-link" id="navItem3" href="#">Submenu3</a><br />
                <a class="dropdown-container-link" id="navItem4" href="#">Submenu4</a>
              </form>
            </div>
            <li id="navDrop2" class="dropdown-btn">
              <a href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
             <!-- add your new class here -->
            <div class="disp-container dropdown-container">
              <form>
                <a class="dropdown-container-link" id="navItem1" href="#">Submenu1</a><br />
                <a class="dropdown-container-link" id="navItem2" href="#">Submenu2</a><br />
                <a class="dropdown-container-link" id="navItem3" href="#">Submenu3</a><br />
                <a class="dropdown-container-link" id="navItem4" href="#">Submenu4</a>
              </form>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```